# 99% wa shell locks up, load at 19 crashed root filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, hacking, server-crashes

I suspect my root file system crashed.

`tail /var/log/syslog` => locks

`dmesg` doesn't show anything interesting

I figure I can reboot and rebuild the system if necessary as its imaged, however I'm wondering if there's another way to recover the system?

I can't use `sudo` because it locks up the system, so I need a way to gain root access and the root user is locked.

My next step after that would be unmount/remount root filesytem as readonly, start killing process to reclaim.

**- update -**

So it looks like two runaway process were locking up the system. I'm trying to `kill -9` them and its not working. One turned zombie but still uses a lot of cpu, occasionally the other ignores all `kill` commands.. `-9`, `-1` , `-5`, `-15`

I was finally able to `sudo` into root but sudo is behaving very strangely.

It doesn't prompt for password until I `ctrl + c` and password entry doesn't always seem to succeed -- I wonder if I've been hacked or the system is behaving strangely..

Now my system is at 99%, 0% wa

```
root:/tmp# shutdown -r now
Failed to start reboot.target: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.

root:/tmp# systemctl status reboot.target
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Find and replace the offending disk.

Comment: Just to be clear, processes can't ignore SIGKILL (-9). The reason it doesn't die is because processes in a blocked state (currently executing a system call such as writing to the filesystem) can't be be killed.

Comment: You missed the hardest kill, `kill -11`. Also, you want `ps -ww -fp <pid>` to see exactly what is executing, there. @Michael, failing hard drives usually cause IOWait, in my experience.

Comment: @thecarpy *You missed the hardest kill, `kill -11`.*  Despite it [going to 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven), there's nothing harder than `kill -9`.  If that doesn't work, no other `kill` signal will, either.

Comment: More info: this is an embedded system, swap enabled on usb disk. Two processes heavily using swap but were nice/ionice to idle/best-effort . It seems this may be some race conditions / bugs across a bunch of programs and the kernel with this environment. A reboot set everything back to normal - my disk and rootfs appear OK. My conclusion is disk write / read failed for a program and the process hung on retry. After terminating the processes, system was no longer stuck on io but on waiting for a system call to return, which is why it went from 99% wa -> 0% wa and 0 % sys -> 100% sys.

Comment: Aside: having system management, ie. systemctl, 'talk' to core system programs over a communication protocol is not a good idea. It may be useful for scripting / API, but terrible when a system is heavily loaded. Documentation on bypassing the protocol would be helpful. It appears systemd is not a good use for me and I'll revert to init or roll my own. I like the unix philosophy, simple, effective and limited in scope. Complex actions achieved by chaining simple pieces, systemd while well intentioned adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Welcome to the edge cases that systemd doesn't like to acknowledge. Systemd is hosed and your machine needs to be hard-rebooted. Take your short list of services that *must* be shut down gracefully [eg: databases] and then go read their service definitions to figure out what signal to send to what PID, because systemd is in such a broken state that it can't do anything anymore. In the future you need to more closely monitor your resource usage because systemd performs *very* poorly under resource starvation compared to previous init daemons.